# Howto disable the emacs site-start files permanently?

Tags: emacs, init

When solving [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220980/strange-semantic-error) problem I figured out that I need to disable the site-wise init files in order to get my emacs + CEDET running (everything works nicely when starting emacs using `emacs --no-site-file` but is broken without the additional argument).

I'd like to disable the site-wise init files permanently but as I'm using several different approaches/methods when launching emacs (launcher/panel/terminal) I don't think aliasing it in my `.zshrc` won't work.

I require a method to **permanently disable all site-start files**. Is there any easy way to achieve this? Thanks!

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly `gnus` is not autoloaded but loaded explicitly, which in turn loads `auth-source`, which loads `eieio.el` before I can load CEDET using my `.emacs.d/init.el`. Unfortunately CEDET requires eieio to be loaded _after_ itself. I traced the problem that I linked above back to this conflict. It seems to me that disabling the site-init files completely is the best/easiest solution, is it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a wrapper in `/usr/local/bin/emacs` should allow you to override the default `emacs` system-wide, provided you have write access and a sane `PATH`.

Having said that, advising `eieio` to load `cedet` migh be a more adequate workaround.

Comment: How would I advise `eieio` to load cedet prior loading itself?

Comment: Something like `(defadvice 'eieio (before activate compile) (require 'cedet))` ... Not at my computer so probably not entirely correct.

Comment: I went with the wrapper method for now; it seems to be the easiest solution until I have the time to compile emacs myself.

Comment: Rebuilding Emacs just to solve a load-path issue sounds like even more overkill than disabling the site init files.  You should find the precise problem in the init files and address that instead.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the specific question, it's not possible to disable the `site-start` file without building your own version of Emacs (or, as you mentioned, always running with `--no-site-file`).

If you take a look at the documentation for the variable `site-run-file`, you'll see:

> the run-time load order is: 1. file described in this variable (`site-run-file`), if
>   non-nil; 2. `~/.emacs'; 3.`default.el'.

If running Emacs with `-q` is enough to solve the problem, you can achieve that in your .emacs by setting:

```
(setq inhibit-default-init t)
```

All that being said, it's pretty straight forward to build/install your own Emacs.  You can pretty much cut/paste the commands listed on [this page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BuildingEmacs) (they are `./configure; make; make install`).

Comment: Would I need to apply any additional `./configure` options (except the prefix) when omitting the "standard" site-run-file?

Comment: @elemakil No, by default there is no site-start file (at least none of my builds have any).

Answer (score 0):

When this was originally asked, the answers were correct that the only way to disable `site-start` files was to start emacs with `--no-site-file` or to make a custom build of emacs.

However emacs 27 (relased in 2020) introduced the [early init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Early-Init-File.html), which allows customizing emacs before the usual initialization.

Now you can disable site files by adding the following to your `~/.emacs.d/early-init.el`:

```lisp
(setq site-run-file nil)
```